# How do I break up a large for-loop in Python into multiple files?

Tags: python

In actuality, I have hundreds of lines in a for-loop. It is very painful to edit these hundreds of lines. But let's examine the following, related toy code snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import pytz
import time

central_timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Central') # define the Eastern Timezone (US/Eastern)
current_time = datetime.now(central_timezone) # get the current time in Eastern Time
rounded_time = current_time + timedelta(minutes=(5 - current_time.minute % 5)) #
```

How would I put this into another file, `test_time.py`, then tell that file to execute to update `rounded_time` and use `rounded_time` in a Jupyter notebook, `main.ipynb`?

My actual use case is to have hundreds of lines of code in each of several `.py` that I would call from `main.ipynb`. This will make my code my modular and easier to update.

Comment: Do you have a for loop that's constantly updating those values in main.ipynb?

Comment: Start by putting the code you want to modularize into functions. Then you can move those functions into separate files and use `import` to access them.

Comment: You kind of answered your own question — find reasonable ways to break up the body of your for loop into logical steps and factor each step into a function. You can keep those functions wherever’s most convenient for you from a maintainability perspective. I can’t give much more of an answer without seeing your code, but at that point, it’s good to remember that SO isn’t a code review site.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, you have a for-loop or while-loop running this code over and over again.  e.g:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import pytz
import time

central_timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

while True:
    current_time = datetime.now(central_timezone)
    rounded_time = current_time + timedelta(minutes=(5 - current_time.minute % 5))
```

If this is what you have, you can separate each section of the for-loop into its own function and import and run it in your main file.
e.g:

test_time.py

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import pytz
import time

central_timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

def update_time():
    current_time = datetime.now(central_timezone)
    rounded_time = current_time + timedelta(minutes=(5 - current_time.minute % 5))
```

main.py

```py
from test_time import update_time
from other_files import other_funcs

while True:
    update_time()
    other_funcs()
```

Comment: If I have a print statement in `def update_time()` it doesn't print anything when called in the While loop. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show me your code please?